# Matlab code to split a random data

Tags: matlab, communication

In Matlab, how can I split a random data into two matrices, for example: X(i) is a random vector, where i=1:100, every data symbol is formed from four bits, where x(1) and x(2) are the MSB(Most Significant Bits), x(3) and x(4) are the LSB(Least Significant Bits). I want to split them to get a new matrices  y1(for the MSB) and y2(for the LSB).

**EDIT**
Here is some example code but for some reason it does not seem to work,

```
M=16;
N=10;
c=randi([0 M-1],1,N); 
xx=dec2bin(c); 
for k = 1:N-1
    for j= 1:4
        y1(k)=xx(k);
        y1(k+1)=xx(k+1);
        y2(k+2)= xx(k+2);
        y2(k+3)= xx(k+3);
    end
end
```

Comment: So you want to take the **first** element, `x(1)`, and every **4th** element after that to the **end** and put all of those into a vector? (and likewise for `x(2), x(3) and x(4)`) Can you give us a short example? Do you have any code from your attempts to do this?

Comment: give a simple example. The text it is not very clear.

Comment: Is X a 100x4 matrix? Then y1=X(:,1:2); y2=X(:,3:4);

Comment: I want to split X(i)  into two matrices, for example: X(i)=[1000, 0010, 1100,1001,1000, 0011,......] , y1=[10,00,11,10,10,00] and y2=[00, 10, 00, 01, 00, 11] so, The first new matrix( y1) contains the first two bits from every symbol and (y2) contains the rest of the bits.

Comment: @othmannoor I am afraid your question still needs some clarification. If you want to work with bits, the smallest integer types in matlab is `int8` or `uint8`. The reason has likely to do with that, in most computer arcitectures, the smallest alignment possible is 1 byte. This means that smaller data type would not be needed in most cases. You would need to write some code handling this for you. However, if you instead works with a string stream of bits (`'1001011011...'`)  you need to first split the string into a cell of 4 char elements. Please clarify and I may be able to help better.

Comment: dear Patrik, I wrote a simple code, but the answer is still does not what I need M=16;
 N=10;
c=randi([0 M-1],1,N);
xx=dec2bin(c);
for k = 1:N-1;
 for   j= 1:4;
     y1(k)=xx(k);
     y1(k+1)=xx(k+1);
     y2(k+2)= xx(k+2);
  y2(k+3)= xx(k+3);
 end
end

Comment: Forget your loop and just use `y1 = xx(:,1:2) ; y2 = xx(:,3:4) ;`. Also look at [Matrix Indexing in Matlab](http://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html), it will save you a lot of hassles.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hoki It's work correctly.

Comment: Thanks Partik, your answer is so useful I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @othmannoor You are welcome, consider accepting the answer if it worked as you wanted :)

Comment: @patrik Dear Patrik, Can you please recommend good online training for MATLAB in communication to learn MATLAB in a good way? I am interesting in Hierarchical modulation.

Comment: @othmannoor I am afraid I do not know about any online training about Hierarchical Modulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you wrote seems to have some issues. I think some of the problems is based on a misunderstanding of matlab. I will write a short list of some issue here:

1) There is no string class in matlab. Instead there is char arrays. Further, Matlab does not use pointers or reference in the same ways as Java or c++. This means that you cannot have a vector with char arrays as you have there. This also mean `y1` and `y2` must be a matlab cell or a matrix to store the data.

2) If `c` is a vector, then `xx` will be a matrix and `size(xx) == [length(c),dec2bin(max(x))]` So to say, each string of binary values is a row and every row is exactly large enough for the the largest string to fit, eg.

```
a = [13,257];
b = dec2bin(a);
```

where b is a 2x9 matrix since `b` needs at least nine bits. So to your problem. I will vectorize the solution and also use the extra agument in `dec2bin` to lock the number of bits to 4. Try this,

```
function [msBit, lsBit] = test()
M=16;
N=10;
if M>16
    error('M must not be greater than 4 bits');
end
c=randi([0 M-1],1,N); 
xx = dec2bin(c,4);
disp xx
disp(xx)
disp ' '

% Take the 2 most significant bits from every row
msBit = xx(:,1:2);
% Take the 2 least significant bits from every row
lsBit = xx(:,3:4);

disp msb
disp(msBit);
disp ' '
disp lsb
disp(lsBit);
```

It is of course possible to work with `int8` as well, then we need to use the [bitwise operaton functions](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/bit-wise-operations.html). This is more difficult and the result will of course be an int. So `1100` will be represented by `12`. This does not seem to be what you are after though, so I will not do this here.

Hope it works and good luck!